# validate postal code field in qform

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to validate fax number field in my qform

```
if(objFormEdit.postalCode.defaultValue.length <=5){
            objFormEdit.postalCode.validateFormat('xxxxx','numeric', "Postal Code requires either a 5 or 9-digit number in either the format 'xxxxx' or 'xxxxx-xxxx'.");
        }
        else{
            objFormEdit.postalCode.validateFormat('xxxxx-xxxx','numeric', "Postal Code requires either a 5 or 9-digit number in either the format 'xxxxx' or 'xxxxx-xxxx'.");
        }
```

Its working fine but when i enter 1234-12345 then its change it to 12341-2345 and does not show any error. why its happening. I want error message in this case also.

Comment: what is `validateFormat` function?

Comment: Do you actually use the postal code to store fax numbers or that's the bug?

Comment: my mistake its postal code only

Answer (score 0):

Used custom function in qforms as below and it solved my problem.

```
 function __isValidPostalCode()
        {
              var regx="^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$";
              var regxObj = new RegExp(regx);
              if( regxObj.test(this.value) == false )
              {
                  this.error = "Postal Code requires either a 5 or 9-digit number in either the format 'xxxxx' or 'xxxxx-xxxx'.";
              }
        }
```

Load the function

```
_addValidator("isValidPostalCode", __isValidPostalCode);
```

called it as below

```
objFormEdit.postalCode.validateValidPostalCode();
```